# How to verify new AdMob bank account (payment option)?

Tags: settings, admob, payment, verify, bank

I've just recently upgraded to the new AdMob format (26th of August 2013), and I'm now unable to find the section for verifying my bank account. Where can this be done?

According to their own help system it should be under "Payment settings", which is where I'm at in the screenshot, without any option except removing the bank account I want to verify.

[image: Where I believed the verification would take place]

Comment: My new upgraded admob  doesn't show "Available forms of payment". The payment settings shows everything as Adsense payment settings. How long did you waited to appear adding back account stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the same issue. According to the Admob support page:

> If you don't see this link, our system may not have been updated. Please wait a couple of days and check again.

Source: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3006274?hl=en-GB

I guess we'll have to wait a few days before it'll appear.

Comment: This problem is now solved for me, as I am able to verify. The verify link was below the "Bank account ..." part of my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the link yesterday but I had no record of the "Google validation bank transfer". This morning I recieved the bank transfer but the link disappeared...

I guess it's not a coincidence and that we just have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here but don't worry guys. go to payment > paymentsetting in admob site.
there has been clearly mentioned that:

> You can only select a payment method after the finalized earnings in your transaction history have reached at least $10.00 or your local currency equivalent.

It means that you should just put the ads in your app, when ur earning will reach to the target currency i.e. $10 , so then this option will appear.